# Get text from next tag

Tags: php, regex, simple-html-dom

I have a html snippet that looks like this (of course surrounded by other html):

```
<p class="finfot3"><b>Header:</b></p>
<p>Text</p>
```

How can I get `Text` from this? I'm using simple_html_dom, but I can use something else if simple_html_dom can't do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is untested, but you might be looking for simple_html_doms `next_sibling()` method.

`$html->find('p[class=finfot3]')->next_sibling()->innertext()` **should** return the contents of the second `<p>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Find the p element with the class. Then use

- [`$e->next_sibling()` - Returns the next sibling of element, or null if not found.](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_traverse)

where `$e` is the element with the class.

For better alternatives to SimpleHtmlDom, see [Best Methods to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('~<p>(.*)</p>~', $html, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```