# DOM/Javascript: get text after tag

Tags: javascript, dom

How do I get the text "there" that comes after a tag in an html document:

```
<p><a>hello</a>there</p>
```

I see that there is a way to do it with xpath:

[Get text from next tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920695/get-text-from-next-tag)

but I'm not using xpath and am hoping not to have to start just for this. I realize that I can get ALL the text inside the p tag, but I want to get just the "there" text, as well as know its relationship to the p and a tags. It doesn't seem to be anyone's child or sibling. (You can assume that I can get any of the other elements/nodes so it can be relative to those.)  Every DOM tutorial seems to ignore the fact that text can occur outside tags.

Thanks.

Comment: The question you linked to is using PHP - are you using PHP ? or just JavaScript ?

Comment: just javascript. So another reason that answer won't work!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use several ways to get the tag and the text

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p'); // first p on the page
console.log(p.lastChild.textContent)

let ps = document.querySelectorAll('p'); // all p on the page
console.log(ps[0].lastChild.textContent)

// using tagName
p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
console.log(p.childNodes[1].textContent)
```

```html
<p><a>hello</a>there</p>
```

Comment: yes, it really is that simple :) "there" is a child of P. For some reason that wasn't working for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

use this .. http://jsfiddle.net/2Dxy4/

This is your HTML --

```
<p id="there">
   <a>hello</a>
   there
</p>​
```

In your JS

```
alert(document.getElementById("there").lastChild.textContent)​
```

or

```
alert(document.getElementById("there").childNodes[1].textContent)​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lastChild and textContent to get it: http://jsfiddle.net/M3vjR/

Answer (score 0):

Well if you use jQuery there is a sneaky way to get this

`x = $("<p><a>hello</a>there</p>")`
`x.contents()[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can find children tags of your parent tag:

```
var pTag = ...
var childNodes = pTag.childNodes;
```

Finally you can find your text in a `text` node after `a` node.

Answer (score -1):

You have to first get the a attribute innerhtml then take total innerhtml with using substring you can have your there part ..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var getA=$("p >a").text();
var getA=getA.length;
var takeTotal=$("p").text();
var result=takeTotal.substring(get);
alert(result);
});
```